# Can I get Google's OAuth2 to display a mobile friendly approval page?

Tags: oauth-2.0

I am working on a mobile app that will hit some Google APIs, authenticating using OAuth2.

It's working pretty well but when I navigate to the approval Uri, Google is returning what looks like a full blown desktop app approval page. It doesn't look too bad but I'd prefer to get the stripped down mobile version that you could ask Google's OAuth 1 to display.

(from http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth_ref.html)

```
btmpl

(optional) Forces a mobile version of the approval page. The only accepted value is "mobile". This is a Google-specific parameter.
```

I've tried adding it to the OAuth2 approval Uri but no joy. So if I'm using the [Google installed application auth flow](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp.html), are there any options for indicating that the request is coming from a small screen device?

The oauth endpoint I am using:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://localhost&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile&client_id=XXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OAuth 2.0 URL that you are referring to already has a mobile-friendly version available. However, unlike the OAuth 1.0 URL, there is no URL parameter to force it, instead it uses user-agent detection to display the appropriate version depending on the browser. At least it works fine on my Android device (I haven't tried with any other devices though).

Comment: Note that it doesn't work for WP7 though...see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6891813/mobile-oauth-ui-failing-to-load-in-wp7